# Saving image through Angular and Spring boot

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, docker

I'm doing an spring boot project where for each object has an image, actually I'm saving all the image in the assets folder in angular, thanks to the object File with spring where I save the path in a field
Every image are displayed on Angular thanks to the (<src="springPath">).

For this I have a problem when I dockerized my application because the user can upload the image but Angular can't fetch that image for unknown reason.

Is anybody had this problem and can suggest me where to store/fetch the image or how to solve this problem, thanks!!

```
pathtoSave = "county-fe\dist\county-fe\assets"
```

I also tried to save in the `"county-fe\resource\src\assets"` but with no luck

```
 public void saveFile(String regional, Integer id, Binary image) throws Exception {
        URL url =ResourceUtils.getURL("classpath:"+pathToSave);
        if (image != null) {
            File fileToSave = new File(url.getPath() +"\\"+ this.regional(regional, id) + ".png");
            if (fileToSave.exists()) {
                log.error("Image for {} and regional: {} already exist! file: {}", id, regional, fileToSave);
                throw new Exception(String.format("Image for country: %s and region: %s already exist!", id, regional));
            }

            if (!fileToSave.exists()) {
                log.info("file doesn't exist: {}", fileToSave);
            }
            // Try-with-resource
            try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileToSave)) {
                out.write(image.getData());
                out.flush();
                log.info("file saved: {}", fileToSave);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            log.error("No image set");
        }
    }
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
ADD target/World-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar target/springboot-docker-city.jar
EXPOSE 8090
CMD ["java", "-jar", "target/springboot-docker-city.jar"]
```

My docker compose:

```
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI: mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: user
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:r
  web:
    build: ./WorldBE/target/classes/county-fe
    ports:
      - 80:80
  api:
    build: ./WorldBE
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
volumes:
  county:
```

My compiled spring boot project

[image: 1]

My Spring boot/ angular application

[image: 2]

Comment: Can your share a Dockerfile of the spring-boot project, I believe the issue may be the mounted volume of docker.

Comment: @Goffity, Hi thanks for answering, I will share my dockerfile e compose now, I was navigate online to find the problem and I found that I can't update my jar, (I was saving all the images in the static folder and then get them via link), so from here I got 1 solution, saving images in the database, do you know if I can do something to save/update/delete images, thanks

Comment: After the build process is successful, you cannot update the JAR file. You have many ways to store images on a web application, such as saving them to an external folder and reference path to store in a database or saving images in a database in BASE64 format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the build process is successful, you cannot update the JAR file.

You have many ways to store images on a web application, such as saving them to an external folder and reference path to store in a database or saving images in a database in BASE64 format.

If you want to save images to an external storage you should mount a volume from the host machine to the container.

```
services:
  DB:
    ...
  web:
    ...
  API:
    ...
    volume:
      - ./application/images:/path/to/save/images/
volumes:
  county:
```

Then in the API to get/fetch the image, it takes the data at that path and converts it into a stream before sending it over the network.

Comment: Hi @Goffity, I have the same problem and I want to store the image to an external folder then get in my angular tags, when I have to store a new one should I do new File("./application/images:/path/to/save/images"); or I have to give another path? Thanks for answer me

Comment: Hey @Goffity actually is worked I'm just wondering about one thig, the file already has some images inside, when I add the file to the volume it saves all the images or when I share my docker image with other users I had to share my file too or the file is saved in the docker image?

Comment: A mounted volume is similar to telling a container where the path's contents reside. while adding data to a mounted disk from the host or a container, respectively. The details could have changed. The data is kept even if the primary volume of an image is removed when it is running and a mounted volume is attached. However, the data won't see the container if you don't start the container informing you where to bind volume.
https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Comment: @Sonn You should be mounted the folder, not the file.